# Cookie troubles with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, session, cookies

I was trying to get cookie value using `@Cookie`. But then I get 400 error if cookie value is null. What's wrong?
This is my controller:

```
    public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map,
            HttpServletResponse response, @CookieValue("flag") String flag) {



        response.addCookie(new Cookie("flag", "In use"));
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting `required = false` in `@CookieValue` annotation:

```
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map,
      HttpServletResponse response, @CookieValue(value = "flag", required = false) String flag) {
```

By default spring expects cookie header to be present and throws exception otherwise:

> Default is true, leading to an exception being thrown in case the header is missing in the request. Switch this to false if you prefer a null in case of the missing header.
>
> Alternatively, provide a defaultValue, which implicitly sets this flag to false.

Comment: What does this parameter mean?

Comment: @JohnSmith is means that the cookie is optional and, if not present, the annotated parameter will be set to null.

Comment: Also, how can I set life time?

Comment: @JohnSmith once you have a `Cookie` instance you can use `Cookie.setMaxAge()`

Comment: ok, but this not solves my problem... because I NEED TO USE cookie, and it always comes null =/